# How to display the saved content of CKEditor5 in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor5

I am using CKEditor5 React Component Framework.I have successfully integrated the CKEditor in my project.And Being Able to use it.
But the problem is that I have to save the Content of the editor to the database and then display it to website.. All I get in the content

`<blockquote><p>Hello from CKEditor 5!</p></blockquote>`

And While Displaying it does not applies the css of CkEditor to show ..

Setup for CKEDITOR IS

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import Classiceditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';


export class ClassicEditor extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            content : ""
        }
    }
    onCashange  = data => { 
        console.log( "Called" );
        this.setState({
            content : data.getData()
        })
     }
    render() {
        Classiceditor.builtinPlugins.map( plugin => console.log(plugin.pluginName) );

        console.log("State", this.state.content);
        return (
            <>
            <div className='App'>
                <h2> Using CKEditor</h2>
                <CKEditor
                    editor = { Classiceditor }
                    data = "<p>Hello from CKEditor 5!</p>"
                    onInit = { editor => { 
                        //console.log( 'Editor is ready to use!', editor )
                     } }
                     onChange = { ( event, editor ) => { 
                         this.onCashange( editor );
                         
                        // const data = editor.getData();
                        // this.onChange( data );
                        // //console.log( { event, editor, data } );
                      }}
                    onBlur = { editor => 
                    console.log("Blur", editor) }
                    onFocus = { editor => { 
                        //console.log( "Focus", editor )
                     } }  
                />
            </div>
            
            <div className='editor'>
                     { this.state.content }
            </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default ClassicEditor
```

Comment: did you solved this?

Comment: Yes, I did solve this. But, I had to create an instance of CK Editor, with editing disabled. But we changed to froala later. Because It is much easier to use and their documentation is also good

Comment: Hi Shubham, On Form Submit, text entered in the CKEditor is not coming. Please help what needs to be done.

Comment: @TestUser You might need to check out the documentation for resolving your issue. They have a complete example on how to create the CKEditor instance and all. Also, try this: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/getting-started/frameworks/react.html

Comment: Check out my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77504885/4671908

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 2 options:

- Download or using script to get Full CSS and include it in your project.
  [Link here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/content-styles.html#the-full-list-of-content-styles)

Note: You have to add a parent container with a class name **ck-content**

- Create a custom CKEditor 5 build from the source code with all the CSS (both UI and the content) extracted to a separate file
  [Advance Guide](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/advanced-setup.html#option-extracting-css)

You can see more here from the documentation:
[Content Styles](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/content-styles.html)

Answer (score 3):

React does not allow you to render `html` code directly. Instead you have to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute to do so. Do the following to solve your problem,

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.createMarkup()} className='editor'></div>
```

and have a method on the class as

```
    createMarkup = () => {
      return { __html: this.state.content };
    }
```

This will make sure that you are not rendering the raw HTML to the page.

You can read more about this [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Comment: what about if i want to set the font-size of the text here ?

Comment: you will be open to cross-site scripting if you use dangerously set. You should use something like React-html-parser

Answer (score 2):

you can just install npm package like `npm i react-render-html`
[enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-render-html)
and use it like :

```
 <div className='...'>
    {renderHTML(someHTML)}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer to above question:

```
<div style={{wordWrap:'break-word',display:'inline-block'}}>
<div className="editor" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{_html:this.state.content}}/>
</div>
```

Comment: Also to show it in the same styling as in editor you should add css class 'ck-content' with style file of ckditor