# CK Editor returns <p> tags instead of whole content when i call it from API in React JS

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm building app with React and Strapi and to add an article im using CKEditor 5 for the content.

In the editor it all works fine it accepts headings bolds paragraphs but when i read it on front end it just gives content wrapper in `<p>` tag

**This is my CKEditor input code**

```
<CKEditor
    name="longContent"
    editor={ClassicEditor}
    data={modifiedData.longContent}
    onChange={this.handleCKchange}
/>
```

**The onChnage handler**

```
handleCKchange = (event, editor) => {
    const data = editor.getData();
    this.state.modifiedData.longContent = data;
  };
```

**This is how i call it on front end**

```
 <div className="post-longContent">
       {modifiedData.longContent}
  </div>
```

This is how it outputs
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56928946/how-to-display-the-saved-content-of-ckeditor5-in-react-js). previously i use dangerouslySetInnerHTML but it is not recommended i presume.